# How can I solve this ssh-agent problem?

Tags: ssh, git, ssh-agent, gnome-keyring

I'm using Linux Mint, and have not been able to get gnome-keyring to unlock automatically at login, it seems.

A symptom of my problem is as follows:

```
$ ssh-add
Identity added: /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa (/home/me/.ssh/id_rsa)

$ git pull
WARNING: gnome-keyring:: couldn't connect to: /tmp/keyring-Nmf3J3/pkcs11: No such file or directory
```

How can I make it that git can push/pull without any passphrase input from me?

I realize there's several things here with gnome-keyring, and ssh-agent, but have not been able to nail it down.

Running `ssh-add` during a session means that I am no longer asked for my passphrase for SSH/git.

The problem is that I would need to run `ssh-add` during each session - I must be missing how to have Gnome's keyring unlock at login.

```
$ export | grep GNOME          
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/tmp/keyring-hjMM4V
GNOME_KEYRING_PID=1961
```

It happened again during the same session as the first edit. I did `git pull` and got `WARNING: gnome-keyring:: couldn't connect to: /tmp/keyring-hjMM4V/pkcs11: No such file or directory`.

```
$ env | grep SSH
SSH_AGENT_PID=2116
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-OACxJMBY2038/agent.2038

$ ps -fp $SSH_AGENT_PID
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
eoin      2116  2038  0 09:47 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session x-session-manager
```

Comment: Can you run `export | grep GNOME` and post the results.  Have you seen [this](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=783568) bug?

Comment: Looks like a relevant bug. Since I don't always see the warning, I'm not sure if I have a simpler problem simply getting `gnome-keyring` to unlock automatically at login.

Comment: possibly you have another agent than gnome-keyring running. What about `env | grep SSH` and `ps -fp $SSH_AGENT_PID`

Comment: @StephaneChazelas I've added what you suggested, thanks. Yes, I have made life complex with `zsh` and `tmux` running (just to mention that).

Answer (score 2):

What is meant to happen is:

You start a gnome session, part of that a gnome-keyring daemon (which also acts as a ssh agent) starts and the environment of anything started during that gnome session is updated with information on how to contact that ssh agent. The password you issue upon graphically logging in is used to unlock the default keyring.

When you use gnome-keyring as a ssh-agent, you don't want to use another agent like `ssh-agent`.

When your X session terminates, so does gnome-keyring. But your tmux session remains. Then, even if you start another gnome-keyring or ssh-agent, the environment of the processes already started by `tmux` won't be able to talk to it unless you update their environment with the path of the new socket.

What you could do is:

```
gnome-keyring-daemon -r > ~/.gkr
```

And do `. ~/.gkr` in all the shells you want to use the new gnome-keyring

Beware though of which DISPLAY that gnome-keyring-daemon is going to connect to.

Comment: Do you mean this is only for when my X session terminates, in other words whenever I log out and log back in again? I don't have `.gkr`, should I? How can I beware of which display that `gnome-keyring-daemon` is going to connect to?

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I'd try is `apt-get install ssh-askpass-gnome` otherwise if you don't have that package (or some alternate askpass program) installed, then gnome can't prompt you for your password when you need to unlock your key.

You'll also need to have your `DISPLAY` variable set properly:

```
$ echo $DISPLAY
:0.0
```

Also, how are you starting your terminal? There could be an issue with the way you are starting the terminal session and whether or not it inherits from `gnome-session`. This can happen when you use some gnon-gnome program to set your key bindings.

Presuming you use `gnome-terminal` you can check using `pstree`. Here you can see the correct inheritance happening:

```
$ pgrep gnome-terminal | xargs -l1 pstree -s 
init(1)───lightdm(1643)───lightdm(26912)───gnome-session(27049)───xmonad-x86_64-l(27139)───gnome-terminal(26036)─┬─bash(26041)
                                                                                                                 ├─gnome-pty-helpe(+
                                                                                                                 ├─{gnome-terminal}+
                                                                                                                 ├─{gnome-terminal}+
                                                                                                                 └─{gnome-terminal}+
```

Whereas in this session it is NOT inheriting from `gnome-session`:

```
$ pgrep gnome-terminal | xargs -l1 pstree -s 
init(1)───sh(25919)───gnome-terminal(25920)─┬─bash(25927)
                                            ├─gnome-pty-helpe(25926)
                                            ├─{gnome-terminal}(25921)
                                            ├─{gnome-terminal}(25924)
                                            └─{gnome-terminal}(25928)
```

Also, check that `ssh-agent` is being started by `gnome-session`:

```
$ pgrep ssh-agent | xargs -l1 pstree -s
init(1)───lightdm(1643)───lightdm(26912)───gnome-session(27049)───ssh-agent(27091)
```

Comment: It's a bit complicated about what terminal I'm using (my own fault!). My terminal launch command is `mate-terminal --maximize -e tmux` (which I presume *is* gnome-terminal). Furthermore, `zsh` is then loaded within `tmux`. `ssh-askpass-gnome` was installed. `$DISPLAY` has expected result. For the inheritance, `tmux` is sitting under `mate-terminal` with no mension of `gnome-session`. On a separate branch, it's `tmux───zsh───xargs───pstree`. To answer your last question, the output is: `init───mdm───mdm───x-session-manag───ssh-agent`. What do you think? Thanks.

Comment: well, presuming you use gnome (and I think Mint does by default, so unless you've changed it from the default?) then I think not having your `mate-terminal` inheriting from `gnome-session` is the problem. two questions: 1) what is the output of `pgrep -fl gnome-session` and; 2) what action do you take to actually invoke your terminal? from a menu? from a hot-key binding? or ????

Comment: Yes, I'm on Gnome. 1) Output is empty. 2) Very interesting. I usually do `Ctrl+Alt+t`. It's a shortcut I set using the Linux Mint application `Keyboard Shortcuts` using the command I previously mentioned. **However**, when launching `Terminal` through the main "Start" menu, SSH **acted differently**. The Gnome GUI prompted me for my password to my keyring. The option to save this passphrase for later sessions was greyed out, I couldn't select it. (The menu launcher command is also `mate-terminal --maximize -e tmux`.) Does that get us closer? Thanks, aculich.

Comment: If you're seeing the odd behavior with the `Ctrl+Alt+t` that you set in the Keyboard Shortcuts then I think you're probably experiencing a bug in mdm/MATE. What version of Mint are you running?

Comment: I'm one version behind, on Linux Mint 13. But for the menu-accessed terminal, why would it still not let me select "save this passphrase for each time I log in"?

Comment: I think this is your issue. I am using Mint with Cinnamon. If I use the shortcut key to launch _the first_ terminal, `pgrep gnome-terminal | xargs -l1 pstree -s` outputs `gnome-terminal` as a direct child of `init`. However, if I launch it via the menu in Cinnamon it is an ancestor of `gnome-session`: `init───lightdm───lightdm───gnome-session───cinnamon───gnome-terminal`. After launching the first terminal from the menu, all others (even created with shortcut) seem to fork from this and are, therefore, fine. Just launch the first "parent" terminal from the Mint menu. Probably a Mint bug.

Comment: Perhaps this is deliberate and a consequence of Mint's WM (either Mate or Cinnamon) that not all processes are children of the WM. It allows you to restart the WM with all your windows in place. IMO they should still be created as children of `gnome-session` which is the problem.

Comment: @CraftyThumber Re: "just launch the first parent from the Mint menu". Even doing that has the "Automatically unlock whenever I'm logged in" option disabled when asking me for the passphrase.

Answer (score 1):

I think problem on permanently storing password-protected SSH key.

Please have a look at the following resources:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466626/add-private-key-permanently-with-ssh-add-on-ubuntu
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/138892/how-can-i-permanently-save-a-password-protected-ssh-key
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6741349/git-enter-password-before-push-pull

Comment: I'll comment as I go. With the first link, I added ` IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa` to `~/.ssh/config` but that didn't fix it.

Comment: The third link shows basic setup which doesn't seem to go further than what I've already done. Thanks, though.

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your .bash_profile

```
if [ -n "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" \
    -a "${SSH_AUTH_SOCK::13}" = "/tmp/keyring-" \
    -a ! -L "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ]
then
    OLD_AUTH_SOCK="$SSH_AUTH_SOCK"
    eval `ssh-agent`
    mv "$OLD_AUTH_SOCK" "$OLD_AUTH_SOCK"~
    ln -sfn "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" "$OLD_AUTH_SOCK"
    SSH_AUTH_SOCK="$OLD_AUTH_SOCK"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. With this, `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` has a value of `/tmp/ssh-QCndYkdq2025/agent.2025`. Am I missing something? `$git pull` still brings up SSH passphrase prompt.

Comment: Check your permissions on your .ssh/authorized_keys file on the server. It should be 0600.

Comment: On the server? GitHub is the external server, and my SSH key is recorded there. Isn't this more of a local issue, no?

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize you were using github. Yeah, you have no control over that host. You could add multiple keys to your ssh-agent and experiment sshing to localhost to make sure you can auth properly. Also, you can try ssh -vvv user@host and see what's breaking.

Comment: Most desktop Linux systems (Mint included) handle `ssh-agent` properly upon login right out of the box and it is usually roll-your-own things like this that break it. If for some reason your system doesn't handle `ssh-agent`, don't do it by hand. Instead use [keychain](https://github.com/funtoo/keychain) which is well-designed to handle this and related problems. It also works for BSD (Mac) and other non-Linux systems.